# How to dynamically add a layout in android

Tags: java, android

I am having a set of layouts such as expense,transaction and loans and a main page
i want to add the other layouts such as expense,transaction and loans based on user input dynamically to the main page.
Can anyone tell me what i have to use in the code to make these layouts available in the mainpage dynamically

Comment: That link should give you some ideas of what/how to do different things. You'll have to Google a bit, look at the documentation, and give it a try then ask a more specific question. As it stands, someone would have to guess at the layout you want then write the code from scratch for you.

Comment: use this link http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-dynamic-layout-using-xml-add.html